# hapi-auth-jwt2: Add custom attribute to error response

Tags: hapi.js

In hapi-auth-jw2 is it possible to add an attribute in the error response for example when the token is invalid. Because I need to add a `code` attribute to the response but when I tried to add attribute to the err in the `errorFunc` it's not adding the attribute.

```
errorFunc: (err) => {
   err.code = 'token-invalid';
   return err;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to add the attribute `code` directly to the response object as the library calls [Boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom) to return errors.

However due to the fact an invalid token is likely to result in a `401 Unauthorized` you can extend the callback `err` as per the [optional parameters](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2#optional-parameters) to contain whatever custom attributes you want. Take a look at `Boom`'s docs on this response for further information, [here](https://github.com/hapijs/boom#boomunauthorizedmessage-scheme-attributes).

```
errorFunc: (err) => 
{
    err.message = 'foo bar'; // optional
    err.schema = 'error';
    err.attributes = {code: 'token-invalid'};

    return err;
}
```

This will produce a response something like

```
"payload": {
    "statusCode": 401,
        "error": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "foo bar",
        "attributes": {
            "error": "foo bar",
            "code": 'invalid-token' // <---- your custom value
        }
},
"headers" {
    "WWW-Authenticate": "error code=\"token-invalid\", error=\"foo bar\""
}
```